# fail2ban custom filter on multiline

Tags: regex, multiline, fail2ban

Is it possible to catch authentication failure on multiple line with fail2ban regex?

Here is the example :

```
Sep 08 11:54:59.207814 afpd[16190] {dsi_tcp.c:241} (I:DSI): AFP/TCP session from 10.0.71.149:53863
Sep 08 11:54:59.209504 afpd[16190] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:329} (I:UAMS): DHX2 login: thierry
Sep 08 11:54:59.272092 afpd[16190] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:214} (I:UAMS): PAM DHX2: PAM Success
Sep 08 11:55:01.522258 afpd[16190] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:666} (I:UAMS): DHX2: PAM_Error: Authentication failure
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Yeah sure, fail2ban uses [python regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) with the multiline option. In your case, try:

```
"afpd\[[0-9]+\] {dsi_tcp.c:241} \(I:DSI\): AFP/TCP session from <HOST>:[0-9]+\n.*afpd\[[0-9]+\] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:[0-9]+}.*\n.*afpd\[[0-9]+\] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:[0-9]+}.*\n.*afpd\[[0-9]+\] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:[0-9]+}.*PAM_Error: Authentication failure"
```

As you can see, you just have to put `\n` where needed. Don't forgot to set the `maxlines` option to 4 in your case, so that fail2ban uses 4 lines to match the regex. Your filter file should look something like:

```
[Init]
maxlines = 4

[Definition]

failregex = "afpd\[[0-9]+\] {dsi_tcp.c:241} \(I:DSI\): AFP/TCP session from <HOST>:[0-9]+\n.*afpd\[[0-9]+\] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:[0-9]+}.*\n.*afpd\[[0-9]+\] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:[0-9]+}.*\n.*afpd\[[0-9]+\] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:[0-9]+}.*PAM_Error: Authentication failure"

ignoreregex =
```

Use fail2ban-regex to test your regex.

Answer (score 1):

Was just looking for a solution for the same problem - but I think that answer given by wpoely86 can lead to blocking innocent IPs - if there are multiple IPs connecting at more or less the same time.

```
Sep 08 11:54:59.207814 afpd[16190] {dsi_tcp.c:241} (I:DSI): AFP/TCP session from 10.0.71.149:53863
Sep 08 11:54:59.207815 afpd[99999] {dsi_tcp.c:241} (I:DSI): AFP/TCP session from 10.10.10.10:53864
Sep 08 11:54:59.209504 afpd[16190] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:329} (I:UAMS): DHX2 login: thierry
Sep 08 11:54:59.272092 afpd[16190] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:214} (I:UAMS): PAM DHX2: PAM Success
Sep 08 11:55:01.522258 afpd[16190] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:666} (I:UAMS): DHX2: PAM_Error: Authentication failure
Sep 08 11:55:01.522258 afpd[99999] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:666} (I:UAMS): DHX2: PAM_success: Authentication succeeded
```

Above, the offending connection came from 10.0.71.149. However, the regex would block 10.10.10.10. In other words, the regex would need to distinguish between afpd[99999] and afpd[16190] (which identify the PID of the afpd process).